# Joining 4 tables in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I cant figure about how to go about this problem. I have done with simple joins but this seems to me complex . Here's what I've got tables

```
USERS
-------------------
ID | NAME | ROLE_ID
1  | BOB  |    1
2  | PETE |    2
3  | JOS  |    3


USER_ROLES
----------
ID | ROLE 
1  | ADMIN
2  | MANAGER
3  | STAFF

CARS
---------
ID | CAR
1  | BMW
2  | MERCEDES
3  | AUDI

USER_CARS
----------------------
ID | USER_ID | CAR_ID
1  |    1    |   1
2  |    2    |   3
3  |    2    |   2
4  |    3    |   1
5  |    3    |   2
```

My Expected output

```
Expected Output
-----------------------------------------------------
ID | NAME | ROLE_ID | ROLE    | BMW | MERCEDES | AUDI
1  | BOB  |    1    | ADMIN   |  1  |    0     |  0
2  | PETE |    2    | MANAGER |  0  |    1     |  1
2  | JOS  |    3    | STAFF   |  1  |    1     |  0
```

1 in the cars column means that the user has that car, 0 means he does not. What would be the basic logic behind this - using loops or whats the efficient way to query??

Comment: Try looking into the [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using pivot function in Oracle

```
with users(id, name, role_id) as (
  select 1, 'BOB', 1 from dual union all
  select 2, 'PETE', 2 from dual union all
  select 3, 'JOS', 3 from dual ),
user_roles(id, role) as (
  Select 1, 'ADMIN' From Dual Union All
  Select 2, 'MANAGER' From Dual Union All
  Select 3, 'STAFF' From Dual),
Cars(Id, Car) As (
  Select 1 , 'BMW' From Dual Union All
  Select 2,'MERCEDES' From Dual Union All
  Select 3,'AUDI' From Dual),
User_Cars (Id,User_Id,Car_Id) As (
  select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
  Select 2, 2, 3 From Dual Union All
  Select 3, 2, 2 From Dual Union All
  Select 4, 3, 1 From Dual Union All
  SELECT 5, 3, 2 FROM DUAL)
----------------
-- End if data preparation
----------------
select * from (
      SELECT u.id, u.name, u.role_id, ur.role, c.car
        FROM USERS U
        JOIN USER_ROLES UR ON UR.ID = U.ROLE_ID
        JOIN USER_CARS UC ON UC.USER_ID = U.ID
        JOIN CARS C ON C.ID = UC.CAR_ID)
PIVOT (COUNT(1) FOR CAR IN ('BMW' AS BMW, 'MERCEDES' AS MERCEDES, 'AUDI' AS AUDI))
order by 1;
```

output:

```
| ID | NAME | ROLE_ID |    ROLE | BMW | MERCEDES | AUDI |
|----|------|---------|---------|-----|----------|------|
|  1 |  BOB |       1 |   ADMIN |   1 |        0 |    0 |
|  2 | PETE |       2 | MANAGER |   0 |        1 |    1 |
|  3 |  JOS |       3 |   STAFF |   1 |        1 |    0 |
```

You Query will be

```
select * from (
      SELECT u.id, u.name, u.role_id, ur.role, c.car
        FROM USERS U
        JOIN USER_ROLES UR ON UR.ID = U.ROLE_ID
        JOIN USER_CARS UC ON UC.USER_ID = U.ID
        JOIN CARS C ON C.ID = UC.CAR_ID)
PIVOT (COUNT(1) FOR CAR IN ('BMW' AS BMW, 'MERCEDES' AS MERCEDES, 'AUDI' AS AUDI))
order by 1;
```

Without using pivot, you can write as given below

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       u.role_id, 
       ur.role, 
       count(decode(c.car, 'BMW', 1, null)) BMW,
       count(decode(c.car, 'MERCEDES', 1, null)) MERCEDES,
       count(decode(c.car, 'AUDI', 1, null)) AUDI
  FROM USERS U
  JOIN USER_ROLES UR ON UR.ID = U.ROLE_ID
  JOIN USER_CARS UC ON UC.USER_ID = U.ID
  JOIN CARS C ON C.ID = UC.CAR_ID
group by u.id, 
         u.name, 
         u.role_id, 
         ur.role
order by 1;
```

Comment: This is so cool! but what if we add another car "MAZDA", we will have to edit the query. Cant we automate this ?? in the PIVOT IN expression . I tried PIVOT (COUNT(1) FOR CAR IN (SELECT CAR FROM CARS)) but its giving missing expression error some how

Comment: That is the basic requirement with row to column transformation, you need to have the list with you in the very beginning unless you are using pivot returning xml. So, if you want to add another car, you have to modify your query. Pivot was introduced in Oracle 11G, I guess your version of Oracle is lower than that.

Comment: No i am using 11G itself

Comment: Ok, got it, you cannot use `FOR CAR IN (SELECT CAR FROM CARS)` unless you are generating XML using Pivot.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll figure that part. Thank you.